# How do I use jsx syntax in vue files in vue3

Tags: jsx, vuejs3

For example, I want to use these codes in `Hello.vue`:

```
<template>
  <RenderComponent :data="hello" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CustomComponent',

  setup() {
    const name = ref('Lily')

    const hello = computed(() => {
      return <span>Hello {name}!</span>;
    }) 
    return {
       hello
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

But IDE will throw error like "Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax."

I have already install `@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx` and `@vue/babel-plugin-jsx`, and I can use `*.jsx` files successfully.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use jsx inside file named `Hello.jsx` without using `template` and `script` tags, and don't return a jsx  from a property and return a function `()=>` to render the jsx, the following example should work :

```js
import { ref, computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CustomComponent',

  setup() {
    const name = ref('Lily')

    const hello = computed(() => {
      return `Hello ${name.value}!`;
    }) 
    return ()=><RenderComponent data={hello} />
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks~ But I still want to use JSX in vue files.  I find that ```<script lang=‘jsx’>...</script>``` can resolve the problem. But it cannot recognize custom global component. T.T

Comment: `<script lang=‘jsx’>` is  not recommended because you don't the template and style tags